# Which file system is this? file type 0x00, folder type 0x01

Tags: binary-analysis, file-format

Inside a internet radio firmware file I found a file system, and I don't know which one it is.

What I know:

- (The first two bytes are `0A 4C` (maybe magic byte))

  - they are actually not part of the file system data
- Now 4 bytes with the length of the index
- Entries in the index begin with a type of 1 byte:

  - type `00`: File

    - 1 byte file name length
    - x bytes with the file name
    - 4 bytes file length
    - 4 bytes offset of the data in the file system
    - 4 bytes (unknown usage)
  - type `01`: Folder

    - 1 byte folder name length
    - x bytes with the folder name (root folder name is 0 bytes)
    - 1 byte: number of entries/files in that folder

All offsets and lengths are little endian.

What file system could that be? I don't think that the developers built their own file system.

---

The firmware file is from `http://update.wifiradiofrontier.com/Update.aspx?c=ir-mmi-FS2026-0500-0052&m=1122334455&v=2.6.17.EX53300-2RC3&t=Cust-File&n=2.11.12.EX65933-4RC2&f=/updates/ir-mmi-FS2026-0500-0052.2.11.12.EX65933-4RC2.isu.bin`

`binwalk` does not detect the filesystem.

The file system I mean starts at `0x1dc1e6`. I already [wrote a working parser](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/frontier-firmware-fsh1.htm) for that file system, but I'd like to know if that is a known fs type.

Comment: can you share the firmware file? Have you tried using `binwalk` to analyze the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not sound like a well-known file system. Probably it is just something custom the programmers came up with for this project.